# How to send double quote in -d parameter for curl.exe?

Tags: windows, curl

How can I send a double quote char using curl.exe in the `-d` parameter.  I don't want to URL encode the double quote.  Since the `-d` data needs to be surrounded in double quotes, I cannot seem to get it to work.

Or is there another flag for curl.exe that tells it to use a files contents for the whole form post data?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can most certainly escape double quotes. How you do that depends on your operating system and shell, which you fail to specify. On Windows, you'd use the ^ as the escape character.

You can also do this:

```
curl [...] -d @filename
```

...which reads post data from a file called filename.

Google and/or man is your friend.

http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

Comment: The -d @filename was what I was looking for.  When reading the manpage, I thought the @filename only worked for the -F argument.  I didn't realize it worked with -d as well.

Answer (score 63):

My `curl.exe` works with this form:

```
-d "{\"param\":\"value\"}"
```

i.e. doublequotes around data, and doublequotes masked with backslash inside

Comment: Not on Windows, in other Shells yes.

Comment: I tried in Windows 8.1 command prompt and escaping with backslash works fine!

Comment: This works OK for me in Windows 10 DOS Command shell. However, I also had to remove all the single quotes and replace with double quotes. For example here is the Hello World SendGrid v3 API call: curl --request POST --url https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send --header "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_API_KEY" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{\"personalizations\": [{\"to\": [{\"email\": \"to_name@example.com\"}]}],\"from\": {\"email\": \"from_name@example.com\"},\"subject\": \"Hello, World!\",\"content\": [{\"type\": \"text/plain\", \"value\": \"Heya!\"}]}"

Comment: This method works well when passing JSON data on Windows OS.

Comment: This works great on Windows 10. Double quote the whole data payload, and then escape the inner quotes with a \ (whack)

Comment: I sure which CMD recognized single quote ' the same way as Bash.

Comment: Interesting.  That works for me in cmd.exe, but when I try it in PowerShell (using 'curl.exe' instead of 'curl' since 'curl' aliases to Invoke-WebRequest), I get an error message from the service I am querying. It's almost as if it escaped it one time too many along the way.  Weeeeird.

Answer (score 9):

You can surround the data with single quotes and use double quotes inside.

Example in PowerShell

```bsh
curl.exe https://httpbin.org/anything `
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' `
    -d '{ "this": "is proper json" }'.Replace('"', '""')
```

Please note that [cURL is built into Windows 10](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/tar-and-curl-come-to-windows/), but [PowerShell shadows it with an alias](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2016/08/19/removing-the-powershell-curl-alias/), so you have to use `curl.exe`

Comment: And then he'd better pray that there are no single quotes in the data to be posted?

Comment: @martona The question is very specific about double quotes.

Comment: Yes, my problem was with double quotes, but now that i know that -d @filename works, I don't have to worry about any quotes.

Answer (score 9):

For the escaping of double quote question, I'm finding that tripling the doublequotes works from the shell:

```
curl -d {"""foo""":"""bar"""}
```

while doubling the doublequotes works from within a batch file:

```
curl -d {""foo"":""bar""}
```

Which is quite annoying for testing in the shell first.

Comment: I don't think that will work if your JSON has spaces in it. Otherwise there is nothing holding the entire JSON together as a single argument. i.e. `{"""foo""":"""bar is the best"""}`

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing this in Powershell, you will need to quote the whole text block with single quotes and still escape the quotes.  i.e. -d '{\"param\":\"value\"}'

Tested on Win11 VSCode Powershell 7 terminal

Answer (score -2):

There is something called *dollar slashy string*.

```
def cmd = $/ curl -d '{"param":"value"}' -X POST https://example.com/service /$
sh cmd
```