# 500 internal server error for Curl command for POST method(for JSON ) of restful web service using Go

Tags: json, rest, curl, go

There is a file named countries.go 
It imports package github.com/ant0ine/go-json-rest/rest.

referred code from

https://gowalker.org/github.com/ant0ine/go-json-rest#countries

Countries section:Demo of POST DELETE etc

When i try to use command 
   curl -i -d '{"Code":"FR","Name":"France"}' http_URL

It gives

{
  "Error": "invalid character '\'' looking for beginning of value"
}

I have used the package given above .It seems the method in the request.go given as DecodeJsonPayload() ,which implements unmarshal() for JSON ,  have internal server error.

I am unable to correct that.Help appreciated

Comment: Maybe you need to do some string escape characters..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to duplicate your problem with curl on Windows.

Use the following curl command instead:

```
curl -i -d "{\"Code\":\"FR\",\"Name\":\"France\"}" http_URL
```

A related SO question: [How to send double quote in -d parameter for curl.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514199/how-to-send-double-quote-in-d-parameter-for-curl-exe)

Comment: That worked but i was wondering if Unmarshal method can not take care of that??

Comment: No, it can't. Because curl would send `'{Code:FR,Name:France}'` (including the apostrophes) to the Go server. That is broken JSON and the json package requires valid json data.