# Modify Jenkins build information for a job using RESTful API failing with INTERNAL error 500

Tags: json, rest, curl, jenkins

I am trying to modify the `<keepLog>` information of a job's build using the JSON flavor of the rest api of jenkins via curl.
Here is the command which I execute in the terminal :

```
curl -i -X POST http://userName:passWord@jenkinsServerName/job/jobName/jobNumber/configSubmit -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"keepLog":true}'
```

On trying the command I get the following exception:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Expires: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache,must-revalidate
X-Hudson-Theme: default
X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=E03E57536C73B539AE980D2E2E23E21B; Path=/; HttpOnly
X-Hudson: 1.395
X-Jenkins: 1.532.2
X-Jenkins-Session: 52147858
X-Hudson-CLI-Port: 58895
X-Jenkins-CLI-Port: 58895
X-Jenkins-CLI2-Port: 58895
X-Instance-Identity:    MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAk3DSI2DZjwNW5axYcX2GZFGF6k6GjMdrHxJBNdK3jcpMP6B9Va+cj6iEVK8wdrKgr1tr3IbAdmzn0jusEh/CKC1IADwka3FCixrZghZ8kUKVZ82r7LCH34WP8csOEJXgTs13iKgLTEmkmmyQNEYGbfhzDAaFJlWpRuBiReZ0AjcnNnCOJsxqyDjeQMCNkqyTzIIYRSKj+oSseZyhfpUylMVv9ydPm1IuNTwCWZoMYR9Qfs4ggWPmA6T7G8FvQYTLylVbn+D2S44dGFgnvAL0/Sk1kq4hw0OSYyRlnO5PjuLTW3S02p0fjuwCTrgWI5T84pCtBVR3keR9xsgNvsmVoQIDAQAB
X-SSH-Endpoint: idc-ws-arbs-dev.mchp-main.com:58894
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Mon, 26 Oct 2015 05:54:40 GMT
Connection: close
```

> org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/C:/apache-tomcat-7.0.64/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-1.532.2.jar!/hudson/security/SecurityRealm/loginLink.jelly:28:78: <j:invokeStatic> Could not load class: java.net.URLEncoder. Reason: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.net.URLEncoder.encode(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String)
>           at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.InvokeStaticTag.createLoadClassFailedException(InvokeStaticTag.java:177)
>           at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.InvokeStaticTag.doTag(InvokeStaticTag.java:139)
>           at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
>           at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>           at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
>           at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyViewScript.run(JellyViewScript.java:81)
>           at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.IncludeTag.doTag(IncludeTag.java:147)
>           at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
>           at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>           at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
>           at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyViewScript.run(JellyViewScript.java:81)
>           at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.IncludeTag.doTag(IncludeTag.java:147)
>           at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
>           at org.apache.commons.jelly.TagSupport.invokeBody(TagSupport.java:161)
>           at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.OtherwiseTag.doTag(OtherwiseTag.java:41)
>           at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
>           at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>           at org.apache.commons.jelly.TagSupport.invokeBody(TagSupport.java:161)
>           at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.ChooseTag.doTag(ChooseTag.java:38)
>           at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
>           at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>           at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$1.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:98)
>           at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
>           at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
>           at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>           at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
>           at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
>           at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
>           at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
>           at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>           at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
>           at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>           at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
>           at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>           at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
>           at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>           at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
>           at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:120)
>           at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>           at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
>           at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyViewScript.run(JellyViewScript.java:81)
>           at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:63)
>           at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:53)
>           at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyFacet$1.dispatch(JellyFacet.java:95)
>           at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:728)
>           at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:858)
>           at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:631)
>           at hudson.init.impl.InstallUncaughtExceptionHandler$1.reportException(InstallUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:25)
>           at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.reportException(CompressionFilter.java:63)
>           at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:52)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>           at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>           at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2522)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2511)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.net.URLEncoder.encode(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String)
>           at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.InvokeStaticTag.doTag(InvokeStaticTag.java:124)
>           ... 69 more

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, maybe you have a problem with the quotes:

You could try:

```
curl -i -X POST http://userName:passWord@jenkinsServerName/job/jobName/jobNumber/configSubmit -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{\"keepLog\":true}'
```

A related SO question: [How to send double quote in -d parameter for curl.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514199/how-to-send-double-quote-in-d-parameter-for-curl-exe)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in Jenkins. See this: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31618