# Execute curl with nodejs to make a post request error

Tags: node.js, curl

I use the nodejs to execute the curl request post error.

I thought it was a single quote. I changed all the single quotes to double quotes, but it still didn't work.

```
router.get('/getCon',(req,res)=>{
    const util = require('util');
    const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);

    async function lsExample() {
    var cmdStr1='curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" -d "{\"ownerApp":"string",\"createTime":0,\"updateTime":0,\"createdBy":"string",\"updatedBy":"string",\"name":"string",\"description":"string",\"version":2,\"tasks":[\{\"name":"string",\"taskReferenceName":"string",\"description":"string",\"inputParameters":{},\"type":"string",\"dynamicTaskNameParam":"string",\"caseValueParam":"string",\"caseExpression":"string",\"decisionCases":{},\"dynamicForkJoinTasksParam":"string",\"dynamicForkTasksParam":"string",\"dynamicForkTasksInputParamName":"string",\"defaultCase":[\{}\],\"forkTasks":[\[\{}\]\],\"startDelay":0,\"subWorkflowParam":{\"name":"string",\"version":0\},\"joinOn":[\"string"\],\"sink":"string",\"optional":false,\"taskDefinition":{\"ownerApp":"string",\"createTime":0,\"updateTime":0,\"createdBy":"string",\"updatedBy":"string",\"name":"string",\"description":"string",\"retryCount":0,\"timeoutSeconds":0,\"inputKeys":[\"string"\],\"outputKeys":[\"string"\],\"timeoutPolicy":"RETRY",\"retryLogic":"FIXED",\"retryDelaySeconds":0,\"responseTimeoutSeconds":0,\"concurrentExecLimit":0,\"inputTemplate":{},\"rateLimitPerFrequency":0,\"rateLimitFrequencyInSeconds":0\},\"rateLimited":false\}\],\"inputParameters":[\"string"\],\"outputParameters":{},\"failureWorkflow":"string",\"schemaVersion":0,\"restartable":false,\"workflowStatusListenerEnabled":false\}" http://localhost:8080/api/metadata/workflow'

    const { stdout, stderr } = await exec(cmdStr1);
    console.log('stdout:', stdout);
    console.log('stderr:', stderr);
    return res.json({'data':stdout})
    }
    lsExample();

})
```

Error message：

```
stdout: {"code":"INTERNAL_ERROR","message":"INTERNAL_ERROR - Unexpected character ('o' (code 111)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n at [Source: HttpInputOverHTTP@304473c1[c=1059,s=STREtOverHTTP@304473c1[c=1059,s=STREAM]; line: 1, column: 3]","retryable":false,"instance":"localhost"}
```

Comment: Welcove to Stack Overflow. Why do you want to use `curl` , rather than node.js built-in `http` library, or perhaps `request` module? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158933/how-is-an-http-post-request-made-in-node-js

Comment: The escapes are not  consistent, each double-quote sign should be escaped: `\"ownerApp":"string"` should be `\"ownerApp\":\"string\"`...

Comment: @Mehdi     Because it is to realize the function of calling the Conductor, the engineer who deployed the Conductor let me use the curl to carried out

Comment: @Mehdi I added \ to the front of the double quotes, but I still get the above error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send double quote in -d parameter for curl.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514199/how-to-send-double-quote-in-d-parameter-for-curl-exe)

Comment: Please edit the question with the adapted version of the code with `\` characters.

Comment: `curl` or a `POST` `http` request sent directly with `node` should have the same effect on the server.

Comment: @Mehdi Thank you very much, I am now adjusting to such ""ownerApp"":""string"", which can be executed normally.