# Vimeo API upload using tus with curl on Windows 10

Tags: curl, vimeo, vimeo-api

I have sent the following request to Vimeo:

```
curl -X POST https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos -H "Authorization: bearer XXXXXX" -H 'Accept:application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4' -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d '{"upload":{"approach":"tus","size":"999999"}}'
```

I have tried every combination of single quote, double quotes, space, no space in the request. But the only valid response I can get is the following values in the form parameters:

```
    "complete_uri": null,
    "approach": "post",
    "size": null,
    "redirect_url": null,
    "link": null
},
"transcode": {
    "status": "in_progress"
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this is your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15828662/3704546

tldr, using curl in Windows you'll need to use double-quotes and escape them in the data with `\`. So your request should look like this:

```
curl -X POST https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos -H "Authorization: bearer XXXXXX" -H "Accept:application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{\"upload\":{\"approach\":\"tus\",\"size\":\"999999\"}}"
```

Comment: Brilliant.  Many thanks.  In fact, the link you gave provided the answer.  Single quotes are  apparently a no no with curl in Windows.  Here is the code that works:

Comment: curl -X POST https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos -H "Authorization: bearer XXXXXXX" -H "Accept:application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{\"upload\":{\"approach\":\"tus\",\"size\":\"999999\"}}"

Comment: @crecy Yes! That was it, thanks for clarifying. I knew Windows was an either/or situation with types of quote characters.