# Building an external adapter for a chainlink-node, getting the "syntax error: unexpected token in JSON at position 0?

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, chainlink

I'm following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=65NhO5xxSZc&list=LL&index=9&t=150s on building an external adapter for a chainlink node. After following the instructions and listening to port 8080 on my CMD terminal, I type the curl command on another CMD terminal and get the following error:
[image]

The template that I'm using :
https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/CL-EA-NodeJS-Template

What I have tried so far:

- double-checked all the modules installed
- switched to my desktop computer
- deleted and re-copied the repo
- tried on Postman with same error

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a windows machine, try surround the JSON in double-quotes instead of single quotes, and try replace the internal double quotes with escape characters. ie:

```
-d "{\"param\":\"value\"}"
```

reference: [How to send double quote in -d parameter for curl.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514199/how-to-send-double-quote-in-d-parameter-for-curl-exe)

Comment: Aha, ok...so now my curl is : curl -X POST -H "content-type:application/json" "http://localhost:8080/" --data '{ "id": 0, "data": "{\"from\": \"ETH\", \"to\": \"USD\"}" } ' ,  but I get unamtched close bracket error ? Should I put escape character in data and id too ?