Curl Patch in VBA / VBS using Shell.Run produce server error
Patching json data to a json-server with curl in a VBA Shell produce an error.
The same methode works flawless in Python. What do I wrong in VBA ?
Sub set_val()
    Dim tmp_shl
    Set tmp_shl = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim cmdln
    'cmdln = "curl.exe -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PATCH -d "{"st": false}" http://localhost:3000/variables/general/isXlOpen"
    cmdln = "curl.exe -H ""Content-Type: application/json"" -X PATCH -d ""{""st"": false}"" http://localhost:3000/variables/general/isXlOpen"
    tmp_shl.Run cmdln, 0, True
End Sub

'general' dictionary on json-server
{"day_cnf": {"last": "2024-10-13 17:36:30", "sop": "2024-10-13 09:00:00"}, "isXlOpen": {"st": True}}

The above script produce following json-server error, how avoid this error ?
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
INFO:aiohttp.access:::1 [14/Oct/2024:07:29:40 +0000] "PATCH /variables/general/isXlOpen HTTP/1.1" 500 245 "-" "curl/8.9.1"


Not familiar with the details of the curl syntax, but -d "{"st": false}" looks odd

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15828662/478884  others: https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+cmd+curl+escape+double+quotes+site:stackoverflow.com
